# very simple copying a file from my jar

Tags: java, file, jar, path

Ok, so I wanted to open a pdf file that I put it in my jar, so I needed to copy the file from the jar to my disk, and I did so by the following code:

```
InputStream is = Jar.class.getResourceAsStream("images/lol.pdf");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("753951741.pdf");
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
os.close();
is.close();
```

my question is:how do I control where the file is created?
When I execute the program It's created under C:/Users/Buba
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
File file = new File("c:/753951741.pdf");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

In this case the file will be created in C:/

For more information about File in Java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)